# How to use Polly for retry mechanism on specific exception?

Tags: c#, concurrency, polly, retry-logic, cosmos

I am trying to implement retry mechanism on `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#resolving-concurrency-conflicts)). There are some ways to that, like add counter or have logic in `catch` block to retry (this link shows that).

Here, I am trying `Polly` to do that and not getting desired result.

What am I missing here? Current, logic goes to catch block and throws the error instead of retry.

Code:

```
public class MyService
{
  private readonly ILogger<MyService> _logger;

  // Using Polly for retry
  private readonly RetryPolicy _policy = Policy
           .Handle<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>()
           .WaitAndRetry(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

  public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger)
  {
    _mapper = mapper;
  }

  public Task<ServiceResponse<MyDto>> UpsertSpecificationsWithRetryAsync(MyDto myDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    // Expecting this to be called 3 times in case of failure, every second
    return _policy.Execute(async ct => await UpsertSpecificationsAsync(myDto, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
  }

  public async Task<ServiceResponse<MyDto>> UpsertSpecificationsAsync(MyDto myDto,
           CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    try
    {
     
     // To test the retry mechanism
      throw new DbUpdateConcurrencyException();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
      _logger.Error(message: $"Exception while upserting options. AtdDto: {{@atdDto}} Exception: {{@exception}}",
          args: new object[] { myDto, exception });

      return GetExceptionServiceResponse<MyDto>(exception.GetBaseException().Message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You catch the exception and do not re-throw it. So there is no exception for polly to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this :

```cs
private readonly RetryPolicy _policy = Policy
           .Handle<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>()
           .WaitAndRetry(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

to this :

```cs
private readonly AsyncRetryPolicy _policy = Policy
          .Handle<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>()
          .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

and this :

```cs
public Task<ServiceResponse<MyDto>> UpsertSpecificationsWithRetryAsync(MyDto myDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Expecting this to be called 3 times in case of failure, every second
    return _policy.Execute(async ct => await UpsertSpecificationsAsync(myDto, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
}
```

to this :

```cs
public async Task<ServiceResponse<MyDto>> UpsertSpecificationsWithRetryAsync(MyDto myDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Expecting this to be called 3 times in case of failure, every second
     return (await _policy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(() => UpsertSpecificationsAsync(myDto, cancellationToken)))?.Result;
}
```

And finally, if you want to log the error in the `catch` block, you should `throw` it after loging

```cs
try
{     
   // To test the retry mechanism
    throw new DbUpdateConcurrencyException();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    _logger.Error(message: $"Exception while upserting options. AtdDto: {{@atdDto}} Exception: {{@exception}}",
          args: new object[] { myDto, exception });
     throw;
      ///return GetExceptionServiceResponse<MyDto>(exception.GetBaseException().Message);
 }
```

But for loging error, `Polly` provides it to you and you can do the following instead of using `try catch`:

```cs
 private readonly AsyncRetryPolicy _policy = Policy
          .Handle<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>()
          .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), (exception, _) =>
          {
              //log error
          });
```

Comment: Changing `UpsertSpecificationsWithRetryAsync` to your suggestion throws `Cannot convert expression type 'Polly.PolicyResult<ServiceResponse<MyDto>>' to return type 'ServiceResponse<MyDto>'` error

Answer (score 1):

In case of Polly v7 (or earlier) the policy declaration should be aware of the to-be-decorated method's nature.

In your case your the to-be-decorated method is asynchronous whereas you have defined the policy for synchronous methods.

Either change your to-be-decorated method to be synchronous or define the policy for asynchronous operation.

The latter case is showed by Mohammad Aghazadeh so, I won't it repeat that here. BUT I want to mention two corrections here:

```
return (await _policy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(() => UpsertSpecificationsAsync(myDto, cancellationToken)))?.Result;
```

1. `ExecuteAsync` is enough, you don't need `ExecuteAndCaptureAsync`
2. `UpsertSpecificationsAsync` should receive the `ct` as the second parameter

So, the correct way would be

```
return await _policy.ExecuteAsync(ct => UpsertSpecificationsAsync(myDto, ct), cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Your suggestion is correct. I have selected the above answer since that gave me clarity. Thank you.

Comment: @GThree How does the change this to that gave you clarity? Did you understand the fundamental issue with your solution based on the explanation what he provided?

Comment: Also his suggested solution swallows all exceptions and returns null instead. I don't think that's what you are looking for but maybe I'm wrong with this assumption.